# JSON Data Map Issue with HighCharts + Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, highcharts

I have the follow data returned via JSON

```
{"rows":[{"Date":"07/10/2011","Value":1206,"Action":"Drink"},    
{"Date":"07/11/2011","Value":2288,"Action":"Pie"},
{"Date":"07/12/2011","Value":1070,"Action":"Drink"},
{"Date":"07/13/2011","Value":1535,"Action":"Beer"},
{"Date":"07/14/2011","Value":1721,"Action":"Drink"}],
"page":1,"total":1,"records":5}
```

I am trying to use this data with HighCharts but getting a bit confused.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: fullPath + 'datamap',
  dataType: "json",
  type: 'POST',
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
       var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            var data = {};
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo === 0) {
                    data.name = item;
                } else {
                    data.y = parseFloat(item);
                }
            });
            options.series[0].data.push(data);
        });
    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

  },
  cache: false
  });
```

I am trying to chart "Date" and "Value" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you need to show `rows` values with Highcharts. So firstly your initial data will be:

```
var chartData = data.rows;
```

Now `chartData` is just an array of objects. Use `for` loop to iterate through `chartData` like below:

```
var seriesData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++)
{
    var x = new Date(chartData[i].Date).getTime();
    var y = chartData[i].Value;
    seriesData.push([x, y]);
}
```

After this loop you will have `seriesData` array of points that can be used in Highcharts. Now just render it:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chartContainer',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: seriesData        
    }]
});
```

Voila!

Test this: http://jsfiddle.net/ebuTs/8263/

Comment: thanks a lot! Just one question - I wanted the dates in the format of '07/10/2011' etc as the X-Axis ? any way to edit your code to do this ?

Comment: Wow! Awesome thanks :) My last and final question [and undying thanks :)] is how to get this as an ajax request ? i.e. or just insert this into the `success: function (data) {`

Comment: just one more question ? just wondering why there are double dates at the bottom ? i.e. there are 2x of each date ? i.e. 2x 07/11/2011 etc

Comment: Because of different hours but different days, change the step of ticks or andd time format